# SwiftUI - Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swiftui, crashlytics

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.
```

I am getting these occasional crashes in Firebase Crashlytics which I can't fathom out or reproduce (I'm new to debugging). Here is some of the info logged in Crashlytics but I can't see anything that looks familiar or that points to where its happening.

I'm guessing that something has happened in the background thread that shouldn't have but I have no idea where this is occurring in the app, hence I have not included any code.

Is there anything hidden in this list that I am missing that may give more of a clue? There are more threads listed in Crashlytics if needed but not much is in them.

Thanks in advance.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0xa248 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x17a68 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreAutoLayout                 0xde84 NSISLinExpReplaceVarWithVarPlusDelta
3  CoreAutoLayout                 0x4e60 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
4  UIKitCore                      0xac03c __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
5  UIKitCore                      0xd4544 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
6  UIKitCore                      0xd4154 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke
7  UIKitCore                      0x1022750 -[UIView _postMovedFromSuperview:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1ed38 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x508b88 -[_UITextLayoutCanvasView textViewportLayoutController:configureRenderingSurfaceForTextLayoutFragment:]
10 UIFoundation                   0xb299c __48-[NSTextViewportLayoutController layoutViewport]_block_invoke_4
11 UIFoundation                   0x5f720 __80-[NSTextLayoutManager enumerateViewportElementsFromLocation:options:usingBlock:]_block_invoke
12 UIFoundation                   0x36ea8 __83-[NSTextLayoutManager enumerateTextLayoutFragmentsFromLocation:options:usingBlock:]_block_invoke_2
13 CoreFoundation                 0xa760 __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
14 CoreFoundation                 0x378ec -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
15 UIFoundation                   0x36b78 __83-[NSTextLayoutManager enumerateTextLayoutFragmentsFromLocation:options:usingBlock:]_block_invoke
16 UIFoundation                   0x20210 -[NSTextLayoutManager enumerateTextLayoutFragmentsFromLocation:options:usingBlock:]
17 UIFoundation                   0x1ff70 -[NSTextLayoutManager enumerateViewportElementsFromLocation:options:usingBlock:]
18 UIFoundation                   0x1fa88 -[NSTextViewportLayoutController layoutViewport]
19 UIKitCore                      0x316d0 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
20 UIKitCore                      0x8af4 -[_UITextLayoutCanvasView layoutSubviews]
21 UIKitCore                      0x4cec -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
22 QuartzCore                     0xa4e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
23 QuartzCore                     0x1db9c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
24 QuartzCore                     0x2f098 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
25 QuartzCore                     0x663c4 CA::Transaction::commit()
26 QuartzCore                     0xb6658 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*)
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1bd8 _pthread_tsd_cleanup
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4674 _pthread_exit
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10e0 pthread_main_np
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe80 _pthread_wqthread
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread
```

```
com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xb48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x108c mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7ae00 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x7c044 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x811e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7  GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
8  UIKitCore                      0x3a2d88 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9  UIKitCore                      0x3a29ec UIApplicationMain + 340
10 SwiftUI                        0x1dace8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_895 + 2424
11 SwiftUI                        0x137c24 block_copy_helper.1 + 388
12 SwiftUI                        0x120b44 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_901 + 2804
13 MyApp                          0x496c main + 4372253036 (<compiler-generated>:4372253036)
14 ???                            0x1d3e95948 (Missing)
```

Comment: Impossible to tell but that crash looks like it is caused by UI

Comment: Thanks - so something from the background has updated the UI? Any suggestions on how I can narrow it down given I can't get the app to crash in dev? Its happened 3 times to 3 different users out of around 800 installs. Is it even worth worrying about? Its my first app so unsure if the "odd crash" now and then is inevitable?

Comment: Are they the same iOS version? I would check the code make sure you aren't updating from background somewhere and `async await` or a closure. You likely get a purple triangle in Xcode

Comment: Yes, they're all iOS 16.0.0, different models of iPhone though. I'm familiar with the purple triangle but I don't get any whilst testing. There are plenty of closures that take place after an API call so I'll check through all those carefully. It also has async wait functions for the in app purchases but they are marked with @Main Actor (lifted from the Apple StoreKit2 demo)

Comment: There is likely some incompatibility. Likely you might be able to wait and see if it shows up in the next version of iOS, you might get away with just keeping an eye out.